# Return one out of multiple rows with partially matching entries

Tags: r

I have a dataset with the name of proteome. It has 14 columns and thousands of rows.

```
dput(Proteome)
    structure(list(Protein.name = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
    3L), .Label = c("HCTF", "IFT", "ROSF"), class = "factor"), X..Proteins = c(5L, 
    5L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 7L), X..PSMs = c(3L, 1L, 6L, 2L, 2L, 4L), Previous.5.amino.acids =   structure(c(4L, 
5L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 1L), .Label = c("CWYAT", "FCLKP", "MGCPT", "NCTMY", 
"TMYFC"), class = "factor"), Sequence = structure(c(5L, 1L, 4L, 
2L, 3L, 6L), .Label = c("FCLKPGCNFHAESTRGYR", "GCNFHAESTR", "GFGFNWPHAVR", 
"GHFCLKPGCNFHAESTR", "GHFCLKPGCNFHAESTRGYR", "GNFSVKLMNR"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("Protein.name", 
"X..Proteins", "X..PSMs", "Previous.5.amino.acids", "Sequence"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

The column of interest in this dataset is "Sequence". In row 2 of this column, first two letters of row 1 are missing; in row 3, last three letters of row 1 are missing; in row 4, first seven and last three letters of row 1 are missing.

Rows 2, 3, and 4 reflect the artifacts of the scientific method I have been using to generate the data, and therefore I want to remove these entries.

I want R to return only one of the four rows, ideally row 1, and remove the rest. The way R can do it is by first finding all rows with a matching string of letters and then eliminating such rows while keeping only one. For example, in the above data set, GCNFHAESTR match in all four rows, so I want R to return me only one row, ideally the top one. But I don't know how to do this.

To further clarify, "Sequence" has hundreds of rows with partially matching entries but the matching entries in those rows are different from the one shown in the example above. For example, it is possible that row no. 35 and 39 have the following entries (Row 35: GNYTCAGCWPFK, and Row 36: YTCAGCWPFK). As matching entries in these rows are totally different than the ones in the example above, I can not declare the string beforehand. So, I want to come up with a mechanism that allows me to detect all those rows which have a partially matching entries and then keep only one of them, while delete others.

I look forward to hearing from the experts.

Thanks!

Comment: I think you’re systematically confusing rows and columns in your description. As it stands, the text isn’t really understandable.

Comment: From what I undestood, you want the column `Sequence` to have a set of strings, correct?

Comment: @FelipeAlvarenga yes, sorry that I forgot to mention it in my question. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly, you just need to subset your data according to the presence of the string you want. Use `grepl` for that.

```
aa <- structure(list(Protein.name = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L),
                                              .Label = c("HCTF", "IFT", "ROSF"),
                                              class = "factor"),
                     X..Proteins = c(5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 7L),
                     X..PSMs = c(3L, 1L, 6L, 2L, 2L, 4L), 
                     Previous.5.amino.acids =   structure(c(4L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 1L),
                                                          .Label = c("CWYAT", "FCLKP", "MGCPT", "NCTMY", "TMYFC"),
                                                          class = "factor"),
                     Sequence = structure(c(5L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 6L),
                                          .Label = c("FCLKPGCNFHAESTRGYR", "GCNFHAESTR", "GFGFNWPHAVR",
                                                     "GHFCLKPGCNFHAESTR", "GHFCLKPGCNFHAESTRGYR", "GNFSVKLMNR"), 
                                          class = "factor")), 
                .Names = c("Protein.name", "X..Proteins", "X..PSMs", "Previous.5.amino.acids", "Sequence"),
                class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

It is good for you to declare the string beforehand

```
myStrToDetect <-'GCNFHAESTR'

#the following line filters the data set into those where "Sequence" has the pattern you provided (4 rows)
matching_df <- aa[grepl(myStrToDetect , aa$Sequence),]

Protein.name X..Proteins X..PSMs Previous.5.amino.acids             Sequence
1         HCTF           5       3                  NCTMY GHFCLKPGCNFHAESTRGYR
2         HCTF           5       1                  TMYFC   FCLKPGCNFHAESTRGYR
3         HCTF           5       6                  NCTMY    GHFCLKPGCNFHAESTR
4         HCTF           5       2                  FCLKP           GCNFHAESTR

# This next command chooses only the first line, if there are multiple occurrences
head(matching_df, 1)

  Protein.name X..Proteins X..PSMs Previous.5.amino.acids             Sequence
1         HCTF           5       3                  NCTMY GHFCLKPGCNFHAESTRGYR
```

Comment: Hi Felipe, thanks for taking the time to answer this. Since there are thousands of rows in my dataset and there are several instances where I see overlapping sequences, I can't declare the sequence beforehand. In the example above, I showed only four of such rows. This is why I want to come up with a mechanism that allows me to keep only one of the overlapping rows whenever R encounters such rows. 
Please let me know if this is not clear. 
Thanks!

Comment: I edited the answer to be more precise. If this is not what you are looking for, edit your question with a more precise language. That way we can help you better

Comment: Thank you! I edited the question to further clarify it.